# UILongPressGestureRecognizer not working with Googlemap

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

[image: This is ma screen]

I have a google map and a button, I need to give UILongPressGestureRecognizer for both button and view(which contains view)

```
//Add gesture to Button
    gestureRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(LongPressedHandler)];
    [Button addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer]
```

I have used above code for gesture on Button and it is working fine only if I include the following functions

```
-(void)deactivate
{
    mapView_.settings.scrollGestures =NO;
    mapView_.settings.zoomGestures = NO;
    mapView_.settings.tiltGestures=NO;
    mapView_.settings.rotateGestures=NO;

}

-(void)activate
{
    mapView_.settings.scrollGestures = YES;
    mapView_.settings.zoomGestures = YES;
    mapView_.settings.tiltGestures=YES;
    mapView_.settings.rotateGestures=YES;
}
```

Is there any other way to give UILongPressGestureRecognizer on mapView and button

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try default MapVIew LongPress event in google map

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView
    didLongPressAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate;
```

for more referance u can use this link: http://www.codeitive.com/7mQmqWUkUU/adding-long-press-gesture-recognizer-to-google-map-in-ios.html

i thing this link can help you